# Centering four Buttons into divs using Flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to center hoprizontal and vertically 4 buttons using Flex.
I have two cols. Each col has two buttons.
I´d like to center the buttons horizontal and vertically.
I have tried the next but the buttons are not centered vertically.

[image]

style

```
<style type="text/css">
.flexbox-container {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
}

.flex-item {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-between;
}
</style>
```

markup

```
 <div class="col-sm-8 flexbox-container">
   <div class="col-sm-6 btn-group flex-item">
     <button type="button" id="id_button_add" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">
        <i class="fa fa-remove" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Excluir</span>
     </button>
     <button type="button" id="id_button_add" class="btn btn-warning btn-block">
        <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Bloquear</span>
     </button>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6 btn-group flex-item">
     <button type="button" id="id_button_add" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Gerar Horários</span>
     </button>

     <button type="button" id="id_button_add" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
        <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Filtrar</span>
     </button>                                       
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Centering is really easy with flex.

`justify-content:center;` for horizontal centering.

`align-items:center;` for vertical centering.

```css
.flexbox-container {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    
    /* just so we can see the parent div*/
    border:2px solid black;
    height:100px;
}

.flex-item {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-8 flexbox-container">
   <div class="col-sm-6 btn-group flex-item">
     <button type="button" id="id_button_add" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">
        <i class="fa fa-remove" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Excluir</span>
     </button>
     <button type="button" id="id_button_add" class="btn btn-warning btn-block">
        <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Bloquear</span>
     </button>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6 btn-group flex-item">
     <button type="button" id="id_button_add" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Gerar Horários</span>
     </button>

     <button type="button" id="id_button_add" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
        <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Filtrar</span>
     </button>                                       
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: FWIW, I highly recommend this article by css-tricks if you're just starting out with flex https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Sorry, It doesnt working. I´d like the full height of the container, not 100px.

Comment: I just did a fiz in the markup and all is ok. Thanks